# How to solve link failer in OPNET

Tags: opnet

I am trying to build a network with 3 sub-nets that are connected with cloud as shown in the first figure below by using OPNET 17.5.

[image]

after I finish building everything, I try to check links connectivity 
one of the sub-nets have 3 links failure, as shown in figure 2
[image]

I was trying to delete older links and connect servers again, but the problem is still there!!!
And I am trying to work in OPNET 14.5, and I have the same problem.
How can I solve it, please!!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, and its work!!
First, this problem happens because the switch ports do not have enough to cover all connections. 
To solve this problem, there are 2 solutions:
1. First, delete some PC's then re-connect to servers
2. Or, just use anther switch that has "Adv" in its name because it has more ports.

Answer (score 0):

Before you run simulation after configuration, pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (Verify Link) will help you. When you move the mouse over the failed link, you can see the solution for that.